# Mysqli_fetch_assoc with params instead

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to patch over to params from standard mysqli. I can´t wrap my head around how to target the columns i want with the new way to get results from db. lets say i have table with id, firstname, lastname, and about.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sqlstmt);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query){
    $row['firstname']; 
    $row['about'];
}
```

this is easily done however when i try to use params,execute etc i cant really wrap it.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM medlemmar WHERE firstname=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $firstname,);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

I don't know how to fetch results from specific columns when using second choice and how to make an array of it etc.

In normal case i would just do

```
$array[]= $row['firstname']
```

Comment: This is all covered in the PHP docs: http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: assuming mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $col1, $col2); $col1 and $col2 will be id and firstname, how do i get specific what columns i want?

Comment: Don't use `SELECT * ...` -- be specific in your query.

Comment: And if that is not an option?

Comment: You will have to have as many variables for columns in `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` as you have in your table, and you should expect all of your calls to `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` to break any time you add or remove columns from any tables used in the relevant queries. Alternatively, you can write a wrapper that determines how many columns there are, etc., but that is quite an undertaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use prepared statements, it takes one extra step to get the `mysqli_result` resource from the statement. Then you can use it like you used the mysqli_result you got from mysqli_query().

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, userid FROM somewhere");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row['firstname']; 
    $row['about'];
}
```

This usage requires [mysqlnd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php), which is enabled by default in PHP 5.4+.

If you don't have mysqlnd, you have to bind results, like shown in the answer from @joaofgf.

It's worthwhile to upgrade to mysqlnd for its extra features and better performance.

Comment: and in a standard procedural approach?

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise for you to look up. There are plenty of examples of both styles in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Jokes on you, i will look into it as we are speaking.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the associative bind `stmt_bind_assoc()`
example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, userid FROM somewhere");
$stmt->execute();

$row = array();
stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $row);

// loop through all result rows
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php